# RestKit Many-To-Many Relationship to Self mapping

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, core-data, restkit

I'm having troubles mapping ManyToMany Self-referencing object in RestKit. I'm trying to implement Parent-Child type of relations for Categories of objects. I'm sure it's simple pattern but I can't get it to work: Intermediary table that CoreData creates to store Many-To-Many relations ("Z_PARENT") is not getting populated with the category ids.

**JSON from Remote API:**

```
{
"active": true,
"created": "2012-10-20 18:15:16",
"id": "60",
"name": "A Second Level",
"parent": [
    {
        "id": "59"
    }
], }
```

**My CoreData Object:**

[image]

**My RestKit Mapping Code:**

```
 RKManagedObjectMapping* categoryMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Category" inManagedObjectStore:self.objectManager.objectStore];
categoryMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"backendID";
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"backendID"];
[categoryMapping mapAttributes:@"active",@"created", @"name", nil];

[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"parent" toRelationship:@"parent" withMapping: [ RKDynamicObjectMapping dynamicMapping ]];
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a to many on the parent relationship? Don't you want one parent having many children and not vice versa? I think if you change the child to parent to not be to many what you have will work. child<<--->parent or child*<---->1parent. Hope this helps.

Comment: Absolutely sure, I'm implementing categories: Category may have multiple children and Category may have multiple Parents. Think of multiple levels of Categories where 1 Sub-Category may belong to many Categories. Example could be Categories of groceries where sub-category "Cabbages" belongs to the parent categories "Vegetables" and "Greens" at the same time. And yes you are right about one-to-many that type of relationship is working just fine in my RestKit implementation (for the different object) –